# recording a android robotium automation test at a pcap file

Tags: android, testing, robotium, pcap

I am writing a android robotium automation test, that gets a apk, and runs a test on the apk, by random clicking on views, and inserting random strings into EditText views. all this test runs a few minutes.

I need to record the all "events" in a pcap file. how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try LoadRunner Mobile Recorder. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hp.mobileRecorder

it will record a file *.lrcap file, which is actually a pcap file.

Comment: I believe OP is looking to achieve this programmatically and not using an external app.

Comment: @JamesWong It should be possible to launch the LoadRunner with Robotium. If that's true and if the device is (or can be) rooted then this could work. (Assuming OP doesn't mean something disobvious by "events".) Worth trying.

Comment: In that case, I retract my comment. Thanks @DaveBurt